# comments plugin for post id

Tags: jquery, facebook-like, facebook-comments, facebook-likebox

Probably I am not the first one to ask this.

I found [this post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11350304/populating-a-facebook-comments-box-social-plugin-fbcomments-with-comments-to) matching with my query, but it is also unanswered.

Basically I have a custom app on Facebook where I am showing a page which would come up after clicking on a post on users wall. Now I want to show whatever comments/likes are there on the post on wall on my custom page. I have the post id.

So basic question would be how to use comments/likes plugin to show comments on a post rather than a URL.

I could have tried XID but I noticed that there is not XID for posts.

So, is there a way I can use the comments/likes plugin to show comments/likes from a post_id? Or do I have to make custom HTML for doing this?